# unable to convert varchar to date in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, date

in my data a column called 'duedate' which is in the varchar(5) format has dates stored in the following format '20110725' for 25th july 2011, is there a way in which i can convert this to date format

i tried using

```
cast(duedate as datetime)
```

which did not work 
then i tried to convert it to bigint and then to datetime

```
cast( cast(duedate as bigint) as datetime)
```

which said

> arithematic overflow error

---

Sorry for the confusion it was varchar(50) - typo error, and thanks a lot for the help ill try the things you guys mentioned

Answer (score 5):

If the column is really varchar(**5**), then it can't have values like '20110725', because that would be **8** characters.

Maybe the values were truncated when they were inserted?
'20110725' shortened to 5 characters becomes '20117', and converting that won't work.

I guess the problem is something like that, because as [Mladen Prajdic already said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815619/unable-to-convert-varchar-to-date-in-sql-server/6815659#6815659), converting '20110725' to datetime works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Please see [this table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) of valid date-time conversion codes. The code you will need is `112` which converts from `yyyymmdd` format.

```
CONVERT (datetime, duedate, 112)
```

Answer (score 2):

how didn't it work? doing SELECT cast('20110725' as datetime) works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try running this on your table to find the values that aren't dates:

```
SELECT duedate
FROM your_table
WHERE ISDATE(duedate) = 0;
```

Like Christian said, a `VarChar(5)` won't be able to hold the value you're expecting it to either.